# VBA - concatenate filename with date

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro which saves a file and sends it as e-mail. The issue is when saving the file I get the error saying:

> Run-time error'1004':
>   Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving.

The code in context is:

```
ChDir "C:/Users/username/Desktop"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:/Users/username/Desktop/test-save_" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Forgive me if the mistake is silly but it's my first experience with vba.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,

Joseph

Comment: Try backslashes "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test-save_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try backslashes

```
 "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test-save_
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Your answer solved my issue :)